# Table creation with h2 database

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

I am new to h2.I just using h2 in spring embedded mode with hibernate.I am trying to execute the following scripts using h2.

```
CREATE TABLE acct_authority (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  value varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY name (name)
);
```

The table acct_authority is created without any error.But if i create another table with the following script.

```
CREATE TABLE acct_role (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  UNIQUE KEY name (name)
);
```

It shows error as constraint name allready exists.What mistake i did.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You tried to create two constraints with same name. As you see, both CREATE TABLE statements contain following:

```
UNIQUE KEY name (name)
```

Result is that first one creates constraint named *name*, and second one fails because constraint *name* already exists. Problem can be solved by using unique names. Also in general it makes sense have little bit more descriptive names for database objects. Maybe you can use for example something like following:

```
  UNIQUE KEY acct_authority_name_UNIQUE (name)  
  ...  
  UNIQUE KEY acct_role_name_UNIQUE (name)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I just wanted to add, the only database I know that supports non-unique constraints names is MySQL (there, constraint names only need to be unique within a table). All other databases require constraint names to be unique within a schema.